# Time Trigger Behavior in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, task-scheduler

Consider the following scenario:

On a system running Windows Server 2012 R2, I have created **Task A** in the Windows Task Scheduler.

The task has a trigger to run daily, starting on May 11th, 2016 at 12:15 AM, and repeat every fifteen minutes for 23 hours. In the Task's `Settings` tab, the check box for the option `Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed`is checked.

It is currently 5:00 PM on May 12th, 2016.

If I disable **Task A** in the Task Scheduler interface and wait 16 minutes before re-enabling the task, will the system consider the task missed and run the task?

Additionally, if the task is considered missed and the system runs the task, will the 15 minute repetition resume as well?

I've tried researching this information on TechNet but the [relevant article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841(v=ws.11).aspx) doesn't go into much detail.

If anyone knows of an article that goes in to depth regarding Task Scheduler's time trigger behavior, I would appreciate a link to the resource.

Comment: Yes, it should run. But not immediately. By default it waits 10 minutes. That is how it used to work on Windows 2008 R2 and 2012 as well. However, The repetition time could also change (the schedule) as the runtime changes from this moment. You should also consider configuring 'If task fails, restart every' parameter.

Comment: I also found this Technet article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722178(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: I read that article as well. I guess the root of my question is: what does Task Scheduler interpret "missed" as, primarily in relation to a task being disabled.

Comment: Probably I misunderstood. My apologizes. If you disable the task you created using task scheduler, there is no reason to run or miss the task - if scheduler/scheduled task was not operating. Therefore, it does not consider this as a miss, according to my experience. It will operate according to the schedule. If you disable it at 5 AM and resumes from 5:16 AM, i does not consider this as a miss. According to my experience. :)

Comment: There is nothing stopping you testing it yourself ... then you can  [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @DavidPostill I could test *that* instance, but like I mentioned in my previous comment I want to know what the Task Scheduler considers as "missed".

Answer (score 0):

If you disable the task you created using task scheduler, there is no reason to run the task. Therefore there is no way of missing the task (otherwise there is no logic). If scheduler/scheduled task was not operating, after a system shutdown or something. it should work as missed. However, if you deliberately disable it, it does not behave like that as it was a direct command (through task scheduler). Therefore, it does not consider this as a miss, according to my experience. It will operate according to the schedule. If you disable it at 5 AM and resumes from 5:16 AM, it does not run the task immediately. It will run as 5:30 AM without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

My PC was offline for 2 weeks. It didn't run the task even though the task was not disabled and the schedule had been missed. Of course, the run task if scheduled is missed setting is ticked already. The last run time shows the successful run from last month and the next run time is for next month. Which means that this month, it completely missed the schedule and didn't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

A disabled task is not supposed to trigger and run. So task scheduler ignores it, as opposed to misses it. (And it would make no sense for TS to attempt to run all disabled tasks...)

Missed = task was not activated/launched by TS when it was supposed to (according to Properties of the task); for example, if the computer was turned off or the Task Scheduler service was busy.
It will not be considered as "missed" by TS if TS didn't have to start the task accordin to your overall settings .
In addition to disabled case, another example is: you set to "run only when user is logged on" and computer is shutdown or logged off. According to settings, the task is not supposed to run, so it's not a "miss".

To your second question:
The runs in a repeated task are scheduled by Task Scheduler service at their own fixed times. So if Ist run's start time is missed, say b/c of sleep, TS will schedule it at 10 minutes after the moment TS service resumes. If the subsequent runs' start times are after TS resumtion, then they will not be missed, thus not moved.
So, yeah, TS can mess up a bit the schedule, by postponing the runs it has missed.